# How to properly stub and test a function using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have this basic method which accepts a cookie and returns a valid user

```
const getInitialState = (id_token) => {
  let initialState;
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    if(id_token == null){
      initialState = {userDetails:{username: 'Anonymous',isAuthenticated: false}}
      resolve(initialState)
    }else{
        var decoded = jwt.verify(JSON.parse(id_token),'rush2112')
        db.one('SELECT  * FROM account WHERE account_id = $1',decoded.account_id)
          .then(function(result){
            initialState = {userDetails:{username:result.username,isAuthenticated:true}}
            resolve(initialState)
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            console.log('There was something wrong with the token')
            reject('There was an error parsing the token')
          })
    }
  })
}
```

Since this is a promise - i'm using a chaiAspromised.

Im able to successfully test the first condition (cookie is not preset) with the below

```
  it('should return anonymous user if id_token isnt preset',function(){
    let id_token = null
    return expect(getInitialState(id_token)).to.eventually.have.deep.property('userDetails.username','Anonymous')
  })
```

however , i'm unable / not too sure how to test the second part since it relies both on jwt and an external db call ( which itself is another promise object)

I've tried this so far. Stubbing the db call returns this error which im finding really vague

```
 1) GetInitialState should return a valid user if id_token is valid:
     TypeError: Cannot redefine property: connect
      at Function.defineProperty (native)
      at Object.wrapMethod (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core.js:128:24)
      at stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:67:26)
      at node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:60:25
      at node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/walk.js:28:30
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at walkInternal (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/walk.js:23:45)
      at Object.walk (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/walk.js:49:20)
      at Object.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:52:23)
      at Context.<anonymous> (getInitialState.spec.js:27:11)
```

I guess it isnt allowing me to stub the entire db object. How else can i approach this? I just want both jwt and the db call not throw any error. I'm just testing if a proper object is sent back if the cookie is valie

```
  it('should return a valid user if id_token is valid',function(){
    sinon.stub(jwt,'verify').returns({username:foo});
    sinon.stub(db).resolves() // unsure of what to do here
    id_token = ' Foo----bar '
    return expect(getInitialState(id_token)).to.eventually.be.true
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to over-ride some of pg-promises defaults to over-ride specific methods

particularly set noLocking=true by

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({noLocking:true})
```

**UPDATE-1**

From [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) author. This is the correct way to do it. See option [noLocking](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html):

> If this provision gets in the way of using a mock-up framework for your tests, you can force the library to deactivate most of the locks by setting noLocking = true within the options.

**UPDATE-2**

Interface locking has been removed in `pg-promise` v11 in its entirety. Option `noLocking` no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 sinon.stub(db, 'one').resolves();
```

Comment: i tried that .. but i'm getting the below error ```TypeError: Cannot redefine property: one
```

Comment: how did you get `db`? It's not defined in the source code you provided

Comment: db is an database connector initialized from the `pg-promise` library .. ```const db = pgp(cn)``` where cn is and object with username/password to db etc